# Mutable Date class fix

Tags: java, immutability

I am just wondering what would be the correct method of making the code below immutable.

```
Date d = new Date();
Scheduler.scheduleTask(task1, d);
d.setTime(d.getTime() + ONE_DAY);
Scheduler.scheduleTask(task2, d);
```

Comment: What does 'immutable code' mean? Do you mean making a `Date` instance immutable?

Comment: Yes. Date is by nature Mutable isn't it? so how could the code above be made immutable. Is it possible

Comment: A Date instance yes

Comment: @GreenCoder Your question is unclear: a bit of code is not mutable or Immutable - a class can be. What are you trying to achieve and why do you want immutability?

Comment: It's just a question I have here. Examine the code and outline in detail a potential issue that might exist and suggest a solution.

Comment: So I am wondering what could I change with the above code to make it safer.

Comment: @GreenCoder How about creating your own class (ex. `ImmutableDate`) by wrapping `Date`? For example, we may hold `Date` instance as a `final private` member (ex. `dateValue`) of `ImmutableDate`, and initialize `dateValue` in the constructor `ImmutableDate(year, month, day, ...)`. Don't provide any setter methods, than we may be able to say that an `ImmutableDate` instnace is immutable.
(See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/imstrat.html)

Comment: Yes I understand you now @hunminpark. I just make a class that follows the Immutable class guidlines and instantiate it within that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't make that immutable. Immutability is a *property* of an object. It says that, once instantiated, an object's internal state does not change.

The [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) class, for whatever reason, was not designed to be immutable. This is illustrated nicely by the ability to change the value it contains:

```
d.setTime(d.getTime() + ONE_DAY);
```

If you wanted to change your code so that it was not *mutating* this object, you could do something like:

```
Date firstDate = new Date();
Scheduler.scheduleTask(task1, firstDate);
Date secondDate = new Date(firstDate.getTime() + ONE_DAY);
Scheduler.scheduleTask(task2, secondDate);
```

---

If you can avoid it, do not use `java.util.Date`. There was a [new Date/Time API](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/jf14-date-time-2125367.html) added in Java 8 located in `java.time`. The classes located in there are immutable and are often better choices.

Comment: Thank You. I can see what you mean.

Comment: @GreenCoder No problem. I just added a little bit about the new date/time stuff added in Java 8.

Comment: I can understand the issue now. The code uses the same Date instance for both tasks which could cause concurrency problems.

Comment: Yep. Depending how the scheduler works, you may end up with both tasks scheduled to occur at the second task's time.

Comment: I understand. Thank You for your explanation @Michael.

Answer (score 0):

Date object implements clone method, so you can clone your date (d) object instead of making references. In your example would be like this:

```
Date d = new Date();
Scheduler.scheduleTask(task1, (Date) d.clone());
d.setTime(d.getTime() + ONE_DAY);
Scheduler.scheduleTask(task2, (Date) d.clone());
```